# Is this a regular expression BUG?

Tags: javascript, ios, regex

```
var url = 'https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MzAxNjczMTQxMA==&mid=504131096&idx=1&sn=c2fe41152807821b7916fa9539a0cf87&scene=1&srcid=0718JR98ETFngTl6mDsNRfhK&key=77421cf58af4a65374324bd2f16d7fdd913230b5ab4bd48a72759cc99919893795265ff20c0c8a79c676e636f789899c&ascene=0&uin=MjAzOTExMTUxMg%3D%3D&devicetype=iMac15%2C1+OSX+OSX+10.11.5+build(15F34)&version=11020201&pass_ticket=kA76WNrCKCEZ3JyEii3tYs88BCmLEM%2FI4LPD%2FtHBzoPjYzI9t7seUadtUUVQ9677';
var reg = /^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(([\w\.]+)\.(?:com|cn|love|net|com\.cn|org)(\/|#|!|%|\w|\d|&|\?|-|=|~|\.|\+)*)$/;
url.match(reg);
```

I want to test a string a validate URL or not, but the match statement will lead the process to CRASH! -- the browser or the iOS App, will not respond afterwards, CPU is 90%+ all the time, maybe in a infinite loop??
Is my reg something wrong or is this a BUG of regular expression?

I tested in JavaScript (http://regexr.com/), node, and iOS, they return timeout or no respond (crashed).

Comment: One thing is certain: the problem is catastrophic backtracking. The `(\/|#|!|%|\w|\d|&|\?|-|=|~|\.|\+)*` group is killing it, replace with a character class - `[\/#!%\w&?\-=~.+]*`.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the last alternation group has several branches that match at the same location in the string (namely `\w`, `\d`), and the `*` quantifier set on that group makes backtracking work hard to try all possible combinations before the match fails.

You need to use a `[\/#!%\w&?\-=~.+]` character class:

```
/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(([\w.]+)\.(?:com|cn|love|net|com\.cn|org)[\/#!%\w&?\-=~.+]*)$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dV1sL0/1)

Note I kept the `-` escaped inside the character class so as not to ruin the regexp if the pattern is going to be updated in the future (`-` can be put at the end or beginning of the regex pattern to denote a literal hyphen, but some developers tend to add symbols to the end of the character class, and sometimes create a range with the `-` without knowing that).

Comment: To be more precise: certainly the easiest fix is just to remove `\d` from your last group, and [it will already be working](https://regex101.com/r/lC1hA5/1), but a character class solution is [much more efficient](https://regex101.com/r/jT8pR3/1) (691 steps vs. 4590 steps).

Comment: Awesome! Your answer is very clear and correct. I didn't know I can't put (\w|\d) at the same time, but it still will works for most test string values (that's why I didn't find this error early). And yes, I want to capture the (s) to decide  is it http:// or https:// or empty. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let me precise again: you may use `\w|\d`, but when you use it inside a larger pattern, and set a quantifier to the alternation group, catastrophic backtracking will happen sooner than later. **When using alternations, it is best practice to make sure no branch can match at the same location**. So, do not use `(catastrophical|catastrophic)`, use `catastrophic(?:al)?`. Although if used as is, this is not a problem... I hope you get it :)

Comment: Yes, I get it, thanks! And yes, I used http(s)? instead of  (http|https)  :)

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comment, I want to capture it

Comment: Sorry. Removed the comment and the hint from the answer.